# Java operation performance better under load than with pauses between data

Tags: java, performance

I have an application that receives data to be processed somewhat infrequently. For example, one relevant message every five minutes. However, once a message arrives performance is very important.

If I run a test and push data through the loop below with a 50 millisecond delay between messages the loop generally takes between 90 and 150 microseconds. If the delay between inbound messages is increased to 5 seconds then the loop takes 300 to 500 microseconds to run. Increasing to 20 seconds or more increases processing time to 500-900 microseconds.

```
Optional<TriggerText> headlineResult = exclusions
                                                .parallelStream()
                                                .filter(exclusion -> keywordCheckString.indexOf(exclusion.pureTextValue)!=-1) 
                                                .findFirst();

if(headlineResult.isPresent()){
    item.setMatchedExclusion(headlineResult.get().textValue);
    exclude = true;
}
```

- keywordCheck is always a relatively small String. Fewer than 200 chars
- exclusions has around 1000 entries
- TriggerText is just a wrapper around a String and pureTextValue is a short string. Generally less than 30 chars
- Based on testing parallelStream is always faster in target env

I need this loop to run as quickly as possible once a message arrives but relevant messages are generally minutes apart. Even though it is at the microsecond level a 3x to 10x change in performance when messages are far apart seems high.

Is there a way to tell the JVM to keep the exclusions list "hot" for fast checking? Or can the compiler be directed to inline the function? The exclusions are loaded once at application startup and never change.

Comment: Hi, could you create a standalone example of what you are seeing?

Comment: are your exclusions static or do they have to be computed all the time? I wrote an example up based on random strings (1000) and testing another random 200 character string, and it always take 1-0 ms, regardless of sleep times.

Comment: @pandaadb They change over time but are static for a given application run. I've considered doing some code generation to make them static strings in the code. Currently they are initialized from a db. Keep in mind a result of 0-1 milliseconds is the same as what i'm seeing. The variation I see is at the microsecond level.